# How to display contents of a dictionary that takes String and Xmlnodelist as parameters?

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, xmlnodelist

I want to output the contents of the dictionary i made that takes string and xmlnodelist as parameters but it only outputs the node.key, without the node values which are xmlnodelists.

```
Dictionary<string,XmlNodeList> chDictionary = new 
Dictionary<string,XmlNodeList>
XmlNodeList chNode = xmlfile.GetElementsByTagName("CH")
foreach (XmlElement node in chNode)
{
  chDictionary.Add(node.GetAttribute("Name"), node.ChildNodes);
}
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, XmlNodeList> xnode in chdictionary)
{
  Console.WriteLine(xnode.Key, xnode.Value);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Your dictionary value is a XmlNodeList so you need to extract all the nodes from the list to display results.

Comment: isn't what im doing? im confused

Comment: No.  The value of your dictionary isn't one node, it is a list of nodes.  So you need to get the innertext of each node in the list.